# Prove there is an element $x \, \epsilon \,G$ with $\left |x \right | = 2$ if and only if $\left |G \right |$ is even

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

1) Let $G$ be a finite group. By considering the size of the set $ \left \{ x \epsilon \, G \, : \left |x  \right | \geqslant  3 \right \}$ prove there is an element $x \epsilon G$ with $\left |x  \right | = 2$ if and only if $\left |G  \right |$ is even.

(I assume simply using Lagrange's theorem isn't allowed here)

2) Is there a group $G$ with elements $x, y, z$ such that  $\left |x  \right | = 5$,  $\left |y  \right | =\left |z  \right | =7$ and  $\left |xy  \right | = 35$ but  $\left |xz  \right |  \neq35$?

Comment: There's something wrong with 1 because if $|x|=2$, then $x\not \in G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), $G$ should at least be a group for $|x|$ to be defined. Lagrange's Theorem only gives one implication - for the other, consider inversion as a set map from $G$ to itself.

For (2), just take something like $\langle x, z \mid x^5 = z^7 = 1 \rangle \times \langle y \mid y^7 = 1 \rangle$

Comment: Oh damn, I meant group. Sorry

Comment: @John01010: Registering will help u to track your activities here easily. :-)